# Nagios - Configure a hostgroup to include all the hosts of another group?

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I can define a hostgroup in Nagios to include hosts X, Y, Z. Can I set a hostgroup to include all the hosts from another group as well? So any host in hostgroup B would be included in hostgroup A? And any service that runs for group A would also include all the hosts in group B?

In theory one could do this by just copy and pasting a few lines, but is there a 'cleaner' way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest hostgroups but not in the way you're describing. See this writeup:

[Nagios 4 and hostgroup inheritance](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectinheritance.html)

Comment: Oh interesting. Does that work in nagios2 (the current version in debian)?

Comment: Afaik: no. That's not the only reason I'd recommend going to Nagios3 (or Icinga when it's out).